# Strapi debug: Error on attribute departure in model

Tags: python-3.x, postman, strapi

today when I try to run my Strapi with some exercises, there was an error showing that inversedBy attribute flight not found target api::airport.airport. However, the command shows Admin UI was built successfully. but I cannot access the Admin panel and do anything with it. It seems that the error is belonging to one of the content, but the entire API is not working. What should I do? Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3rq.png)

Thank you.

Firstly, I tried to run the start command(npm run develop) for several time, it keep reporting same error.

Secondly, I tried to access the administration panel directly, it is apparently that I failed.

Hopes someone can help me to figure out, how can I solve this bug/error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.
The issue for me related to a problem where the 'key'(i.e. attribute key in JSON) didn't match that was referenced by the model in the mappedBy & inversedBy.

e.g. `mappedBy:"f_light"` should point to
`"f_light":{type:"relation",...)` --
At least that was the problem for me

[Strapi Docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/v4/data/sql-relations.html) on how the schema is supposed to look

My issue: `Error on attribute a_token in model a-request(api::a-request.a-request): inversedBy attribute a-requests not found target api::a-token.a-token`
This occurred because I inversedBy:'a-token' when the attribute key was 'a_token'. Changing them so they matched solved my issue ('a-token' -> 'a_token').

The naming conventions of mappedBy, inversedBy, and the attribute keys MUST use '_' instead of '-' for spaces, otherwise it will fail the naming convention tests.